How do I transform a function delegate to IL code
This question is a follow up on Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly "System.Private.CoreLib" could not be found in custom generated assmbly.
I basically want to transform a Func at runtime to IL code, that will then be executed in the generated assembly.
For this I created a function with the following signature:
public void AddExecutingFunctionToIL(ILGenerator parentIlGenerator, TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Func<object[], object> function)


parentIlGenerator is the IL Generator that will call the function.
typeBuilder is the current type builder, where methods will be saved in.
function is the delegate that contains the code, which should be executed, when the IL code is run.

I can't figure out how I can achive this, as referencing function after generating the assembly is not possible (so just calling parentilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,function.Method); won't do the trick. I also tried using the Mono.Reflection package to transform the function delegate to IL code, sadly I couldn't quite figure out how to do this properly.
Help would be gladly appreciated.

Are you asking about how to call an external function delegate from IL? The way I did it is I passed it as this argument, which is arg 0, but hidden in the signature.

@freakish No not really, I want to transform the delegate, so it gets embedded in the ILGenerator and can be called from there.

Can you explain your use case a little more? A Func<> has already been converted to IL code at compile time. Why do you want to "transform" it at run time? What does "transform" mean in this case?

@StriplingWarrior I linked another question, that describes my usecase on top. I generate an assembly at runtime. Now I want to add a Func<> to a method in this assembly at runtime of my assembly generator, so it can be executed at runtime of the generated assembly.

@AaronJunker-Wildi so you want to read a function's IL and then embed it into some other IL? That is either impossible or extremely hard. Let's start with the fact that the delegate might not have IL at all (e.g. native function). And even if it has it can be an arbitrarily complicated closure, that manages arbitrarily many managed objects, which would have to be embedded as well. The only sensible way I see is to have IL of that function, instead of arbitrary delegate.

But even then this is rather hopeless. The delegate can refer to objects and methods that don't exist in the new context. Are you going to embed all dependencies as well? That's quite close to writing a compiler. If it is even possible, IL does allow pointer arithmetic, no? Meaning it'e correctedness is likely to be verifiable only at runtime. Also I can't imagine a use case for that tbh.

Can you clarify what it means to "add a Func<> to another method", what other options have you considered, and why they won't work? For example, could your other method take the Func<> as an argument and invoke it? It may help to provide some code samples showing an example of the Func<> and the C# equivalent of what you're envisioning the emitted code to look like with that Func<> "added" to the method you're creating.

@freakish Yes writing a compiler is what I'm doing. From my own language to CIL. And I thought using C# code by creating Func delegates would be an easy way to achive this.
